Why does my wifi signal suddenly drop despite it being adjacent to the router? (Intel AX201 160mhz)
I was checking my wifi stats today that I suddenly noticed a sudden change in signal strength, from being -19 it went to -23, and along with it the rx-rate also flops from 866 mbs  to 24mbs!
its more apparent in the video :

Here's an un-optimized gif version in case you want to see how fast it actually flips: https://imgur.com/tJpSGFo
Is this caused by the device driver(OS related) or is a it hardware malfunction of 1.the router or 2.my wifi module(ax201)? how can I make sure which is which?

It is likely due to the driver dropping the amplification of signal on the receive side to avoid overloading

thanks, so updating the drivers should be my first attempt at fixing this right? how do I update the drivers? I've read they are packaged with the kernel, and im on 22.04 using 6.8 already! I tried zabbly kernel(6.10) but system wont boot into graphical mode so I'm not sure how to go about this. any help/insight into this is greatly appreciated.
